# Is it save to have the Express Session Secret in plain text when using in conjuction with Angular in a Docker Container?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, express, session

I have inherited a project where currently the front end docker container is setup as below.

Let me also start by saying I am sure this is a trivial question but I am a bit new using Angular/Express/Nodejs.

```js
FROM node:18.12.1

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /app/
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY dist /app/public
COPY express /app
# COPY views /app/views

# Default environment variable for local testing
EXPOSE 80

# serve the appliction
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

In this setup the front end also contains an express folder which is referenced below by the line calling

```
COPY express /app
```

Express then has a server.js file which creates the typical express boilerplate. In this configuration the session is setup as follows:

```js
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(session(
  {
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookieName: 'session',
    secret: 'random_secret',
    duration: 15 ,
    activeDuration: 15,
    maxAge: 30
  }));
```

Is this a huge vulnerability having the secret just stored in the code like this?

I have a similar configuration in the backend for Nodejs where express sets the secret but that secret is stored as an enviroment file.

Again my apologizes if this is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a major security problem.  Anyone who has a copy of the image can find the credential in plain text in your source code; if you've committed it to source control, it will also be there.  Since it's in your source code, if you do discover that the key is compromised, you need to get a code change reviewed and tested and deployed to change it.

The other major problem here is that every instance of your application now shares the same secret.  If this secret is to encrypt a session cookie, it's possible that someone else is running a different copy of the application, but then can extract the session cookie from their copy and send the session to yours, even if they don't know the encryption key *per se*.  That can potentially let them get access to data on your system they're not supposed to.

Credentials, signing keys, and host names, should *always* be passed at runtime.  In Docker the easiest way to do this is via environment variables.  Do not create a `.env` file in a Dockerfile or use Dockerfile `ENV` statements; these contents can be very easily extracted from the image.  Injecting a `.env` file using Compose `volumes:` or `env_file:` should be safe for most uses.